# How to append images to an array based on their background color?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a selected card/image called selectedCard. I have an array of UIImageViews called imageArray. I have a new/empty array of type UIImageViews called newImageArray. I am trying to create a function that checks the imageViews in imageArray and if the image is the same as the selectedCard and background color is blue then append the rest of the images with blue background colors into the newImageArray. Else if, check the imageViews in imageArray and if the image is the same as the selectedCard and background color is white then append the rest of the images with white background colors into the newImageArray. I am creating a card app and the user will be presented with 8 cards to choose from. The user will need to pick 4 of these cards. If their selectedCard is apart of the 4 the picked then I want to store all four in an array. If their selectedCard is not apart of the four they selected then I want to store the four non selected cards into the array.

I have created an if else statement with a for loop inside but I am not having any luck and not sure what to do at this point.

```
func isCardHighlighted() {
    for imageView in imageArray {
        if imageView.image == selectedCard && imageView.backgroundColor == UIColor.blue {
            for imageView in imageArray {
                if imageView.backgroundColor == UIColor.blue {
                    newImageArray.append(imageView.image!)
                } else {
                    print("Can't add because background is not blue.")
                }
            }
        } else if imageView.image == selectedCard && imageView.backgroundColor == UIColor.white {
            for imageView in imageArray {
                if imageView.backgroundColor == UIColor.white {
                    newImageArray.append(imageView.image!)
                } else {
                    print("Can't add because background is not white.")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Basically if the selectedCard is highlighted (background is blue) then I want to save it and the other three highlighted images to the newImageArray. If the selectedCard is not highlighted (background is white) then I want to save it and the other three images to the newImageArray.

Comment: It seems like you want to do the same thing whether selected card is highlight or not?

Comment: Yes that is fair to say. The main point is to make sure selectedCard and the other three cards get appended

Comment: Then you don't need to check whether the selected card's background color is white or blue. The real question is, _which_ other three cards?

Comment: So I have an array or 52 cards. 7 were set randomly to the UIImageView (imageArray) then the 8th spot was the selected card that was picked by the user that was also set randomly to the image array. Now out of the 8 UIImageViews you have to select 4 (it’s up to you to select your selectedCard or not) so you will need to check to see if it’s highlighted or not so it knows which images to save in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem I was having.

Since the newImageArray function was at the top of the class like this var newImageArray: [UIImage]!  I needed to add this-> newImageArray = UIImage to the top of the isCardHighlighted() function.For other new beginners like myself, the reason this needed to be done is because optionals ALWAYS have to be instantiated before you can use them.